# How to clear the cache of SSH in using the libssh.h?

Tags: c++, ssh

I don't want to receive unnecessary content from the channel which I creat by libssh.h,so which interface can help me to deal it.Other methods？

Comment: The obvious solution would be to receive the content and then throw it away; presumably you are looking for something more elegant than that, though :)

Comment: Yes，you are right！

Comment: Define 'unnecessary content'. In general, the channel will have SSH protocol data and anything sent by the remote server.